# Determine the truth value with proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I've been stuck on these two propositions for a while especially how to prove their truth value.
Note that $x$ and $y$ belong to $\mathbb{N}$.
Any idea how to solve this??

$\forall x ~ \forall y ~~ (x \ne 1) \to (xy \ne y)$ 
$\forall x ~ \forall y ~ \exists z ~~ (x > y) \to (x - y = z)$

Comment: Do you define $\mathbb N$ to contain $0$ or not?

Comment: @Watercrystal yes it contains 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you define $\mathbb N$ to include $0$, the first one is false:
Setting $y = 0$ and say, $x = 10$ we find that $x \neq 0$ but $0 = xy = y = 0$.

The second statement holds basically by definition; it is hard to "prove" this without also giving some actual definition of the $<$ relation (which is usually done by saying that $x > y$ if there exists some positive $z$ such that $x = y + z$, or equivalently, $x - y = z$).